# .spec file is creating an empty .rpm

Tags: rpm, rpm-spec

I am trying to create an RPM to just unzip a tar, change some permissions, and then echo something depending on a process. Here is the `.spec` file in question.

```
Summary: Linux agent V.1
Name: Agent
Version: 1.0
Release: 1
License: GPL
Source: Agent.tar.gz
Vendor: test
Packager: test


%description
Test Linux agent

%prep
if ps aux | grep "[u]cx"; then
  pkill -f ucx
else
  echo "Current agent is not running."
fi
%setup -n Agent
%install
cp -r /root/rpmbuild/BUILD/Agent /local/0/opt
cd /local/0/opt/Agent
chown -R root.root *
cd bin/
chown root.root test1 test2
chmod 775 test1 test2
chmod +s  test1 test2
if ps aux | grep "[u]cy"; then
  echo "managerup"
else
  echo "manager down"
fi
%files
%clean
rm -rf /root/rpmbuild/BUILD/Agent
```

When building, the `.spec` file builds cleanly and creates an rpm. It also runs the commands and I get the relevant files in `/local/0/opt`. The build command in question is `rpmbuild -ba agent.spec`. I have tried doing it in verbose mode and it's not really giving me an error either.

However, the `.rpm` file generated is empty and doesn't actually do anything. I think this is a problem with the `.spec` file. However as the output is not giving me an error at all I am not sure what the problem is.

I have been following http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-build-creating-spec-file.html

I believe the problem is the `%files` section. I want it to just deploy the tar into `local/0/opt`, but I am getting confused on where to declare the install directory and where to declare what I want in the package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `/local/0/opt` to your `%files` section

```
%files
/local/0/opt
```

That instructs the rpm build process on where to find files it should package at the end.

You also need to install and manipulate your files relative to your rpm buildroot inside `%install`

```
%install
mkdir -p %{buildroot}/local/0
cp -r /root/rpmbuild/BUILD/Agent %{buildroot}/local/0/opt
cd %{buildroot}/local/0/opt/Agent
```

since the rpm build process will look inside there for files to package.

You might want to clean up that spec file some, including putting `%clean` above `%files` and moving `%install` actions inside `%build`.

Comment: Hi Matt.

I actually tried that before posting. Here is the error it gave me.
`RPM build errors:
    Directory not found: /root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/AutomicAgent-1.0-1.x86_64/local/0/opt`

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately I am still getting an error `+ cp -r /root/rpmbuild/BUILD/Agent /root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/Agent-1.0-1.x86_64/local/0/opt
cp: cannot create directory '/root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/Agent-1.0-1.x86_64/local/0/opt': No such file or directory` I will try setting the buildroot at the top of the spec file. Just to make sure is /root/rpmbuild/BUILD/{name} the default buildroot?

Comment: @Pudding You have to follow the error message and create that directory in the buildroot for the copy to succeed. Updating answer again with the `mkdir`.

Comment: That is slightly confusing for me. In terms of rpm is the buildroot the install directory or is it something else? I thought `/root/rpmbuild/BUILD/Agent` was the buildroot and `local/0/opt` is my desired install directory.

Comment: From what I gathered I thought buildroot was just a temporary area for unpacking. I am confused as why I need to create a file there.

Comment: I got it working after doing some more research on what the buildroot actually does. Thank you for your help